# Is Alfred’s batsuit based on a previous work?

Tags: dc, batman, history-of, costume, the-lego-batman-movie

In *The Lego Batman Movie*, Alfred dons a Batsuit of his own to help the rest of the Bat-family save Gotham.

[image: Lego Alfred]

The movie has several easter eggs and references to previous Batman works so I was wondering if this particular suit was a callback to a previous incarnation of the character or if this suit was created specifically for this movie.

Comment: I vaguely remember this coming up in another answer, and finding out that Alfred did take on the suit for a brief period of time. I think it was due to Bruce being incapacitated, and Alfred feeling that Batman needed to keep up appearances.

Comment: @Gnemlock But was it as classy as the butler batsuit?

Comment: It reminds me a bit of Green Hornet's sidekick Kato's outfit.

Comment: I remember Alfred wore the normal Batsuit once in the animated series so Bruce and Batman could be in the same place, he got the top on backwards though.

Answer (score 6):

While there have been [some Alfred-as-Batman stories](https://screenrant.com/batman-rebirth-alfred-batsuit/) throughout the years (at one point Alfred "tried on" the Batsuit and got hit on the head so he thought he was Batman), I don't think that's an actual Batsuit. Instead, it looks like it's a subtle tribute to [William Austin](http://www.batman-online.com/features/2018/1/26/batman-1943-and-the-comics/4), the man who first portrayed Alfred in the 1943 Batman movie, and whose likeness redefined the role (the original Alfred was much fatter)

[image]

Austin's portrayal of him as a thin, proper English gentleman continues to be how people portray Alfred for the most part.

The Lego Batman Alfred costume has several similarities here, notably the old-style cap, the butler-as-valet topcoat, white gloves (the hands are white), and the pocketwatch (which has kinda been an Alfred Pennyworth staple, because what English gentleman didn't have one?)

The mask is in keeping with the mask that Robin of the same time period wore (minus the Batman curls)

[image]

The logo on the hat is also the original Batman logo

Answer (score 0):

It really resembles Kato from Green Hornet but more closely to the 1966 version and personally I called him "Bat Alfred".

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Can you point to anything which would indicate that that was the creators' intent? I don't readily spot any details to the costume which would indicate a *specific* reference to Kato.

Comment: Alfred pretended to be Batman once in the ‘60s series, but he wore the same bat suit that Adam West wore. It’s not a good match for the black 40s style suit worn by the figurine.

Comment: @Politank-Z It resembles only at the shape of the suit,because this have similarities with Kato(and its an indirect wink to the crossovers realized in the 1966 version)